# What /etc/acl.xml file is used for in Magento 2.0.X

Tags: magento2, xml, acl

I see that most(if not all) of the Magento core modules have a

```
acl.xml file
```

placed in

```
magento-module/etc/
```

I could not find any documentation on this, so basically I want to know, what is this file used for ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the file where you define the **module access control list resources**.

Those resources can be seen under the admin : **System > Permissions > User Roles** section when you click on **Add a new Role** button.

If you're not familiar with ACL, I suggest you read this good article from Alan Storm (even though it was written for M1 it is still relevant to understand the functionality): http://alanstorm.com/magento_acl_authentication

Comment: Let us know if [this topic](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication.html) helps.